# Create XS cut lines having the coordinates of the cross sections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, feature-layer, cross-section, hec-georas

[image: Position of the cross section in the river for which I want to design the cross section cut lines] I am working with HEC-GeoRAS in ArcMap 10.3.1. and I am trying to create the cross section cut lines. I have the coordinates (X,Y) of the cross sections of the river.

Is it possible to create automatically the cross sections in HEC-GeoRAS having the coordinates or is it necessary to create manually?

Comment: Can you provide a screen capture in your question showing what the XS cut lines should look like?

Comment: I can not add here a screen capture. I am trying to copy and paste but it is not working. I know there are two ways to added the XS cut lines in HecGeoRAS: one manually defining lines from the left bank to the right bank crossing the river, and other automatically in ArcMap where the software considered a fixed distance. My question is if there is another way (different to these two) for designing these cut lines automatically having the coordinates of each cross section

Comment: Try edit your question and use the Image button to add in a screen capture.

Comment: I uploaded the image which the location of the cross sections which I want to design the XS cut lines

Comment: I think I remember it's possible automatically but I'm not 100% sure. You might be interested by reading this : http://hecrasmodel.blogspot.fr/2012/07/how-to-draw-cross-sections.html.